# Efficiency of web proxy scripts vs. http proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

I was wondering which class would be more efficient: PHP (Glype, PHProxy), CGI (CGIProxy), or javascript based scripts that run on a webserver, or an http proxy run through squid. Assuming neither class was doing any caching, would one or the other be much more efficient at handling web browsing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on how you integrate these into your server farm.

CGIProxy is a Perl app.
PHPProxy is PHP, of course.

If, for example, you're running MOD_PERL then my vote is for CGIProxy.

Having extensive experience with Squid, you need a lot of RAM to make Squid really perform well.

PHPProxy would be my 2nd choice... (or first choice if not running MOD_PERL).  PHP plugin is faster than forking a perl interpreter that is not built as an apache module (mod_perl).  However, mod_perl apache module appears to be faster than php plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Surely SQUID would be fastest. Its a native application while the script based solutions are interpreted. SQUID needs a fair amount of memory but is that an issue on a modern server?

I've used the Windows port of SQUID extensively and I find it to be excellent, though somewhat involved to configure.

JR